# Sendmail+Dovecot Can't receive emails

Tags: sendmail, mta, dovecot

I have installed sendmail as MTagent on my server. Sendmail works well so, PHP mail() function works perfectly.

After, I decided to exploit my mx records so I installed dovecot as pop3/imap server into my machine following [this instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot):

Well everything seems to be fine except the following step - I can't configure sendmail and tell it where the mail_location folder is. I don't used mbox, so I follow the instructions for MAILDir (in the link above)

Now, when I am trying to connect to my server (from Windows live Mail), I connect, I can send emails, but I can't receive emails

If you think it's necessery I can post dovecot.conf and sendmail.mc files

According [to this link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=114696), changing

`mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir` to

`mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u` solve the problem..

Comment: Dovecot has nothing to do with either sending or receiving mail. It just serves your (already received) mail to your email client. Also, if you say you "*can't*" receive mails, what does that mean? What happens when someone sends you mail? What's in the logs?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I think there is a missmatch between where        sendmail_path_to_save_received_emails and dovecot_path_where_emails_is_saved_by_sendmail Thx for the reply Edit:How can i check my logs?When someone send me email nothing happend

Comment: @user726730 please post the answer in the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [posted in question](https://superuser.com/posts/415458/revisions)

> According [to this link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=114696), changing
>
> `mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir` to
>
> `mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u` solve the problem..